# Windows 10 explorer: drag file into subfolders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

On Windows 10, I'd like to be able to drag files into a folder and also subfolders within that folder, as can be done on OS X. Is this possible in Windows? Right now I have to drag it into a folder, go into that folder manually, and repeat until I drag the file into the desired subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the  **Start button**

Go to  **Control Panel**

Click on  **Appearance and Personalization**

Select **Folder Options**

Under **Navigation Pane**, place a **checkmark** on **“Automatically expand to current folder”**

Click OK

Comment: This isn't exactly the path for Windows 10. Nonetheless, I went to file explorer options and didn't see an option for automatically expanding to current folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but I potentially just answered a similar questions so thought I'd link it here as well.

If you have the `Navigation Pane` enabled you should just be able to drag an item over a folder in the pane and after a second or so it will expand the tree allowing you to hover over a sub directory to do the same thing (or place it in any of these sub directories directly).

There is also an alternative method which requires installing additional software that adds into windows explorer, which I attempted to explain in the following post:

[Drag and Drop Items into Subfolders from Desktop Without Opening an Explorer Window?](https://superuser.com/questions/1121302/drag-and-drop-items-into-subfolders-from-desktop-without-opening-an-explorer-win/1121358#1121358)