# Drag and Drop Items into Subfolders from Desktop Without Opening an Explorer Window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drag-and-drop, user-folders, directory-listing

My inquiry (in my opinion) seems pretty silly but, it's just based on making my "desktop cleaning" a little more convenient.

I like using folders to keep my files neat and organized but, I don't ever take the time to organize my desktop until its already gotten out of hand. I usually wait until the act of pinning a window to the right of my screen... starts to cover my icons.

Despite having a dual monitor setup (on windows 10); having multiple explorer windows open simultaneously (just for the purpose of moving files around) can get pretty annoying... Especially if I'm trying to watch something at the same time. (First world problems... I know)

I was wondering if there was a built in feature (probably not), app, or even some context menu registry editing to make this easier.
What I would love is something similar to "Hover Zoom" for Google Chrome:
So, you've got a file that you want to place in the subdirectory of a folder you have on your desktop... Instead of double clicking the desktop folder, double clicking the desired folder within, and then going back to your desktop to drag and drop the file in that folder.......
->
Is there something that would (from the desktop) allow me to drag the file and hover over a folder, have a little box pop up (showing the folder's contents including subfolders) and, would then allow me to move the cursor to the desired subfolder and release the left mouse button... Thus moving the file to that folder and the pop up box would go away.

I'm aware that for the most part, this desired effect can be achieved by simply having a single explorer window open and using the directory panel on the left side (but without all the flashy pop up box.

I'd just like to do all of it without opening additional windows.

Can anyone let me know if this is a thing or even possible in windows?

Comment: I could not find a way around this. Maybe try Explorer++ ?  https://explorerplusplus.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help you out (I'm Windows 7 but it says it works on Windows 10 as well)!

Download QTTabBar from the following link:
http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/

Instructions on how to install and activate are here (plus loads more information):
http://qttabbar.wdfiles.com/local--files/documents/install.html

Once you've installed and logged back on (you'll need to log off after installing to let it load up), open up a windows explorer and go to `view > toolbars` and select `QT Base Toolbar`.

Now `right-click` on the bar that has (in my case) `Organize`, `Burn`, `Work offline` and `New folder`, etc. as shown below: [image: QTTabBar]

Turn on `Extra view (left)` which will give an extra navigation type view on the left hand side of the explorer window. Setting this window to the desktop with your folders in it, and also setting the main window to desktop as well, you should be able to drag files and hover over a folder. After a few seconds the pop up with sub directories should appear for you to navigate and move your files as needed, another screenshot added below for reference:

[image]

There is a lot more to this program but this will hopefully do what you're after!

Hope it helps.